# two boolean values in if condition to print messages

Tags: java, if-statement

I am looking for any better way to handle this if condition to print values. I am looking to print if both are true i want to print both messages and if not only one message.

```
boolean codeExists = false, nameExists = false;
            for (condition) {
                if(condition){
                    codeExists = true;
                }
                if(condition)) {
                    nameExists = true;
                }
            }
            if(codeExists && nameExists) {
                System.out.println("CodeExists");
                System.out.println("NameExists");
            }
            else if(codeExists) {
                System.out.println("CodeExists");
            }
            else if(nameExists) {
                System.out.println("NameExists");
            }
            else {
System.out.println("Another statements to print");
}
```

do we have any better approach to print the below messages.

Comment: `else` condition should be executed if any of the  `IF` condition fails from above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't use

```
if(codeExists) {
    System.out.println("CodeExists");
}
if(nameExists) {
    System.out.println("NameExists");
}
if (!codeExists && !nameExists) {
    System.out.println("Another statements to print");
}
```

Comment: if both are true i want to print both messages.

Comment: This is exactly what happens here, note I did not use `else if`.

Answer (score 1):

What about ...

```
    if(codeExists) {
        System.out.println("CodeExists");
    }

    if(nameExists) {
        System.out.println("NameExists");
    }

    if(!codeExists && !nameExists) {
        System.out.println("EndUP");
    }
```

Comment: `else` condition should get executed at the last if `IF' condition fails above

Comment: Isn't it resulting in the same behavior? Either `one of both condition is TRUE`, so only one of the upper IF blocks is executed, or `both are TRUE`, so both upper IF blocks are executed, or `non of them is TRUE`, so only the last if is executed.

Answer (score 0):

```java
boolean codeExists = false, nameExists = false;
            for (condition) {
                if(condition){
                    codeExists = true;
                }
                if(condition)) {
                    nameExists = true;
                }
            }




boolean f = true;

           if(codeExists) {
                System.out.println("CodeExists"); 
                f=false;
            }
            if(nameExists) {
                System.out.println("NameExists");
                f=false;
            }
       
            if(f) {
                System.out.println("EndUP");
            }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28028911)

Answer (score 0):

Sir, Use Java stream and don't' forget to check performance. The below example may be helpful at least for others.

```
 List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);//Dummy data
    boolean codeExists = ints.stream()
            .anyMatch(x -> x == 1);
    boolean nameExists = ints.stream()
            .anyMatch(x -> x == 9);
    if(codeExists) System.out.println("CodeExists");
    if(nameExists) System.out.println("NameExists");
    if (!codeExists && !nameExists) System.out.println("EndUp");
```